# Saving application user interface options with rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using a bit of javascript to let users collapse and hide 8 different tables on the main index page.

```
$(".priority-header").click ->   //on click
  $(this).next().toggle()        // Hide Table
  $(this).toggleClass('closed')  //Assign class "closed"
```

I would like to be able to save the user's configuration, so that when they hide or show a table, it remains hidden or displayed the next time they navigate to the home page. What would be the best way to save this user configuration with rails. I was thinking of using a session variable or a cookie, but wasn't sure how to do this. This doesn't have to be a database save, and a session or cookie would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the user localStorage to store the user preference.
This requieres the user to use a modern, HTML5 complient, browser.

```
//When the user click the "hide" button
localStorage['hidePreference'] = 'hidden';

...

//When the page loads
if(localstorage['hidePreference'] === 'hidden') {
    //Hide the stuff with jQuery
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using jQuery, you could use the [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin. There is no browser restriction.

You can replace to calls to `localStorage` of @pdegand59 's solution to `$.cookie['hidePreference']`.